# Compile OpenCV 3.4 and Cuda 9.2 with MS VS15 2017

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake, cmake-gui

I need to do fast image processing so I decide to go for OpenCV with CUDA support. Now I'm trying to build OpenCV as dll to use it in my project, but I am not even able to generate the VS project since CMake keeps giving me this error:
[CMakeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqZTU.png). I am on Windows 10, CMake 3.11 with VS 15 2017 x64 generator, OpenCV 3.4 (the last release).

I have installed CUDA 9.2, 9.1 and 8.0 and set CUDA_HOME environment variable as the CUDA toolkit directory. Nothing seems to work.

Then I try to set the CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR through the CMake GUI, but the CUDA toolkit directory seems to be not the right one and I'm not able to find the CUDA sample directory anywhere.

I have googled a lot, but I found nothing that had been able to help me. Did someone face this very same issue? How can I solve it?

PS: I have successfully created the dll with TBB and IPP (without CUDA) and it is still not fast enough, so I really need to use Cuda.

Comment: CUDA 9.2 was released yesterday. OpenCV 3.4 was released 6 months ago.  Do you think it is surprising that it isn't supported?

Comment: yeah, that's the reason why I try also with 9.1 and 8.0. Are you able to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved using Cuda 9.1 and VS 15.45. To install CUDA in a correct way you need to use custom installation and delete the VS integration, since it seems to have some problems. Once installation is complete, CMake should detect it.

[This](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-compile-opencv-3-4-in-windows-with-cuda-9-0-and-intel-mkl-tbb/) is a guide that could help.